# I want to add popover on button success of copy of text in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, clipboard.js

I am new to jQuery, I want to add popover on button success of copy of text in div. For copy I am using clipboard.js and my code is mentioned below

Here is my code

[image]

Comment: please add your code as text instead of image or screenshot.

Comment: As requested, please add your code as text - will be happy to undownvote if you are willing to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add this :

```
showTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
```

Hope this helps !

**Update**

Code above is from clipboard.js. You don't need to load extra libraries, you can pop everything you want on success. For example you can add :

```
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert('Copied!');
});
```

If you use Bootstrap or another framework you can do easily what you want !

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Thanx for reply sam ..... I tried like this                     clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        showTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
        
    });                                                                                                         but its not working ....Do i need to import somthing..?